# validation and minting policy script

Tags: smart-contract

I am trying to create transaction in which a user interacts with a validator script by sending it 30 ADA.I want the validator script to then send the user a native token while sending the creator of the transaction the leftover ADA how do I do this?

Is it possible to have a validator script that also holds a minting policy?

Can I make a minting policy in which only a validator script is allowed to make the tokens?